# if prepopulated_fields is used, is slugify still needed?

Tags: regex, django

Using a slug is explained in a matter of fact way. A lot of the methods I've seen are to verbose to me. I'm coming from laravel and it wasn't so involved. I know there is a simpler way hich brings me to the following. I see prepopulated_fields 
and I have used it but I am not clear on how it should be used. In the examples using prepopulated_fields they seem brief but they are not explained enough for me to grasp it. Also I see different ways to write regular expressions which I've just learned about via Django. So far all I know about regex is the carrot and the dollar sign. I don't know enough about it to know whats the correct or more efficient way to write it

This is how I've seen it

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug')
    search_fields = ('content', )

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title', )}
```

but it's brief and is explained like I should know and not as a novice. I am using python 3.5 and Django 1.9.

these are some of the regex examples I've seen and I have no clue on what's right

```
 (?P<slug>\d+)/$
 (?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)
 (?P<slug>[\w-]+)/
```

any tutorials or books that would explain this would be greatly appreciated.

my goal is to have a url that looks like this

```
stackoverflow.com/1/ask-a-question
```

Answer (score 1):

First, useful links for learning regexes:

[Official docs (python)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html)

[Online testing your regex patterns (python)](http://pythex.org/)

[A first link of regex tutorial googled (regex in general)](http://regexone.com/)

Second, from your your regex patterns is right the #3 option:

```
(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/
```

\w = alphanumeric sings (0 - 9 and a-z and A-Z)

- = allowing hyphens in the regex

+ = one or more repetitions of characters (without it you will be getting a 404 error in Django)

Third, your goal:

```
# Option n. 1
url(r"^1/ask-a-question", views.your_function, name="your_function",

# OPTION n. 2
url(r"^(?P<slug>[\d]+)/ask-a-question", views.your_function, name="your_function"),

# Option n. 3
url(r"^(?P<slug_1>[\d]+)/(?P<slug_2>[\W-]+)", views.your_function, name="your_function"),
```

<slug> is a value extracted from a URL address and sequences in [] are "validators" (the value is for example a string and not a integer).

Fourth, what do you mean by "slufigy"? (In which context). I did't get it, could you post some codes about it?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont want the numerical value to be hardcoded "......com/2/for-example" where "1" is the id from the database. I'm assuming option three would suit my needs for that   the follopwing is the slugify code from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

slugify(<value>)

Comment: I have never used the slugify code so far and yet am a lot working with slugs (passing values to a function in views). :-)